# Create a new entity, entity alias in Vault and obtain a token for authentication

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I would like to create a new entity in Vault and generate a new token to give access to an user to the UI using the API.

So, I am generating the entity using /v1/identity/entity/name/:name, then consulting the mount accessor in /v1/sys/auth and creating a new entity alias with /v1/identity/entity-alias

I am not adding any policy, that's something I will do later, first I just want to give access to the UI.

So now I create the token /v1/auth/token/create, but I don't find a way to associate that token to the previously created entity.

The same example with username/password works as expected.

How do I associate the token to the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to associate entities directly with tokens. All auth methods are supported except the token auth. The alternative is to use the userpass auth method or to use the AppRole auth method (but without entity, only policies)

Comment: In at least version 1.2.2, it looks like you can now associate entities with tokens.

Comment: @MikeFrank Memory's drawing a blank, but I left myself a note to check this out: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started/apis

Comment: AppRole Auth is just a different type of Auth method. Yes, it generates a token but it isn't the Token Auth method: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/token.html

Comment: @IanHunter do you know how to associate it?